# Ajax request does not work after performing another ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a main view on which there are 2 tables. Using ajax, I invoke a modal textbox window. I fill them in and click add. Records were added normally when the modal window was called not by ajax but simply by a button with the necessary html parameters, and the partialview itself was called on the main form with the help of html.partial. I redid the call to ajax request, the ajax button request to add has stopped working. I can not understand what's the matter, please tell me what is wrong. Here is my code. main view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@model IEnumerable<AjaxTest.Models.Book>

<h2>Каталог книг</h2>

<input id="modRender" type="submit" value="Добавить" />

<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div>
        <table id="tab" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Название</th>
                    <th>Автор</th>
                    <th>Цена</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Author)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Price)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

<h2>Список пользователей</h2>

<body>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Имя</th>
                    <th>Фамилия</th>
                    <th>Возраст</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Users as List<AjaxTest.Models.User>)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Surname)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Age)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

<div id="result"></div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#modRender').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/ModalCreate",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                    $('#mod').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });

        $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Create",
                data: {
                    "Name": $('#txtName').val(),
                    "Author": $('#txtAuthor').val(),
                    "Price": $('#txtPrice').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#tab tbody').append(data);
                }
            });
        });

        $("#result").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#mod').remove();
        });
    </script>
}
```

view modal window:

```
<div id="mod" class="modal fade" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Новая книга</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Название</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Автор</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtAuthor" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Цена</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtPrice" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                <button id="btnAdd" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
Context db = new Context();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Book> books = db.Books.ToList();
            List<User> users = db.Users.ToList();
            ViewBag.Users = users;

            return View(books);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Book book)
        {
            db.Books.Add(book);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return PartialView(book);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ModalCreate()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Comment: Can you check possible errors in browser console? Did the AJAX request reach the controller during debug? Your AJAX code seem fine to me, probably something wrong happened when second AJAX request initialized.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't look right, you have elements outside the `<body>` that should be inside.

Comment: Also using multiple `<body>` tags to separate display values and inputs are not recommended, just use one `<body>` tag and put other HTML elements there.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto The fact of the matter is that the Ajax request is not even executed on the client and not any errors. And the code itself does not enter the controller either. But if I did as I had before (I described the first option at the beginning of the question) in that case there was only 1 Ajax request and everything worked out normally.

Comment: @Barmar yes, i know. I change it, but my mistake is not related to this. And I would like to fix it.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to it. I couldn't figure out what's causing your problem, or I would have posted an answer.

Comment: Are you doing anything that replaces the modal div dynamically? You might need to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @Barmar, thanks, but i want use modal window, but thanks for this option.

Comment: I never said not to use a modal window.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry, i got you wrong.

Comment: @Barmar in ajax requst replaces my modal div, need me html code `$('#result').html(data);`

Comment: Then use event delegation as shown in that question.

Comment: @Barmar, very thanks, it's work, but I can not understand why the code did not work as before.

Comment: @Barmar new code `$(document).on('click', '#btnAdd', function () {`, older `$('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {`

Comment: @Barmar why????

Comment: You bound the click handler to the original `#btnAdd` button. Then you overwrite the DIV with new HTML, all the old event handlers were lost.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto solved the problem with the help of such a code `$(document).on('click', '#btnAdd', function () {`

Comment: @Barmar, and in the old version it turns out to work because my page with the help of Html.Partial added the necessary code to the page right away?